# zsh aliases don't expand even with option `complete_aliases`

Tags: alias, zsh

How do I expand an alias defined when using `zsh -c`?

```
% zsh -c 'setopt aliases complete_aliases; alias d=date; d'
zsh:1: command not found: d
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `eval` to force the `zsh` to parse the alias *after* the code has been read in:

```
zsh -c 'setopt aliases complete_aliases; alias d=date; eval d'
```

In this case, `d` will never expand, so doesn't need to be quoted.

In general you should [properly quote all arguments to `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538533/5353461).

---

`man zshmisc` says:

> ```
>    There is a commonly encountered problem with aliases illustrated by the
>    following code:
>
>         alias echobar='echo bar'; echobar
>
>    This prints a message that the command echobar could not be found.
>    This happens because aliases are expanded when the code is read in; the
>    entire line is read in one go, so that when echobar is executed it is
>    too late to expand the newly defined alias.  This is often a problem in
>    shell scripts, functions, and code executed with `source' or `.'.
>    Consequently, use of functions rather than aliases is recommended in
>    non-interactive code.
> ```

Comment: Better yet, don't use an alias; define a function. A function definition is an ordinary command, and so is guaranteed to be defined before you attempt to use it, even on the same command line. `zsh -c 'd() date; d`.

Comment: @chepner Generally good advice, but in this case I'm writing a generic alias expander for use in `nohup alias`, `nice alias`, `chrt alias` etc.

Comment: Had to scour the internet to find this answer, so THANK YOU! As of 2022, it seems this can be reduced to `zsh -c 'alias d=date; eval d'`.

Comment: Another thank you from 2022! In my case I'm trying to use `viddy` (which is just like `watch`) and to watch the output of a shell alias defined in my ~/.zshrc.  For this to work in viddy this does the trick: `viddy --shell zsh "source ~/.zshrc; eval ll"` (with the alias `ll` in that case).  You'd think I could do `zsh --interactive` but that causes the shell to exit weirdly for reasons I don't yet grasp.

Comment: big thanks from me as well, spared me from fake interactive shell damnation